# Error : Gpu delegate not working with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, tensor, tflite

I am trying to run my model using GpuDelegate ,but when creating the interpreter it gives the error : [image]
Dart version : Dart SDK version: 2.19.6 (stable)
Flutter version : Flutter 3.7.9 
tflite_flutter: ^0.10.0
Flutter code to load interpreter with Delegate

```
Future<Interpreter> loadModel() async {
    final options = InterpreterOptions()..threads = 6;
    // Use Metal Delegate
    // if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // options.useNnApiForAndroid = true;
    options.addDelegate(GpuDelegate());
    // }
    // Load model from assets
    final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(
        "assets/tflite/keypoint_512_320_float16_V3_1_output.tflite",
        options: options);

    return interpreter;
  }
```